# Looking for architectural advice for a meteor app doing audio processing + semantic classifcation

Tags: meteor

sorry if this has been answered before but I'm having troubles even naming what I need, let alone finding advice in existing stack overflow questions.

Basically I've got a meteor app where users:

- can record audio on an native iOS client and send it to the user's dropbox
- create recording metadata to the client and send it to the meteor app when the dropbox upload has been successfully done
- on the server side: auth via dropbox + basic list / detail templates showing the user's recordings
- once the recording object is inserted in the meteor collection (via a server method) I need to do further processing:
  => fetch the audio that has been created on the client from the user's dropbox
  => send that audio to a third party speech to text api to get a text transcription of the audio
  => send the transcript to yet another third party api to process it further and analyse it

All the results obtained from the third party apis will be stored on the recording document.

I would like to do everything reactively but their are special considerations to take into account regarding the dependencies: audio => transcript => concepts

I would like the transcript to be fetched only when the audio is loaded, and the concepts to be obtained only when the transcript exists on the recording, and my views to reflect those dependencies, and I would like this to be done reactively (as soon as the data changes, for example the transcript becomes available, the transcript data is sent to the third party api).

I would really be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction (wether by observing collections, or using deps.autorun in template helpers).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a *Recordings* collection with keys *audioFileURL*, *transcript*, and *concepts*.

You create a *Recordings* document when the user starts uploading their audio file (you can use collectionFS or slingshot or other file-management packages to do this).

The callback from the file upload process sets the value of *audioFileURL.* At that point there is no *transcript* or *concepts* key.

You can publish your recordings with

```
Meteor.publish('myRecordings',function(){
  return Recordings.find({audioFileURL: {$exists: true}});
});
```

This will only publish documents where the audio file has been uploaded and its location recorded in the document. The *transcripts* and *concepts* values will be *automatically shipped to the client as they become available.* You don't have to go back and check when they get loaded because they will just show up on the client whenever they get added to the document. The dependencies manage themselves. Welcome to Meteor.

Comment: Thanks I ended up applying your solution regarding to the publication + background job to autocomplete the data.